# Android - EditText : Hint disapear when Scroll horizontally is true

Tags: android, line, android-edittext, hint

I use a EditText view with a (Hint : text)

I want to reproduce the (Single line : true) EditText's attribute which is deprecated.

So I use those attributes and values :

(Lines : 1)

(Max lines : 1)

(Scroll horizontally : true)

And it works fine.

But there is a little problem the (Hint : text) attribute is now hidden.

How can I bring it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here's the thing.
The problem wasn't the inputType "text", it was the Gravity.
When you set the Gravity of a TextView to "Center", the "Hint" disappears.
The way to make it back is to set the Ellipsize to "start".

```
<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:hint="Hint"
android:inputType="text"
android:gravity="center"
android:ellipsize="start" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need for single line is [`android:inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute.

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: android:gravity="center" makes the Hint disappear